# Как организовать рейтинг на сайте по клику на кнопку?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Пытаюсь решить вопрос с постройкой велосипеда очередной раз. Мне надо организовать топ записей по клику на кнопку избранное. Но не просто ещё отображался топ по количеству кликов но и что бы был реализован счетчик изменений кликов за сутки то есть условно говоря сегодня на пять человек больше подписалось выводится +5 если отписалось то -5. Если описаны  такие решения скиньте пожалуйста ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно абстрактно поставлен вопрос, кнопка избранное на сайте одна или она (для данной категории,для продукта, или просто для сайта)?

> > Мне надо организовать топ записей по клику на кнопку избранное.

кликаешь на кнопку увеличиваешь счечик в БД на 1 (для данной категории,для продукта, или просто для сайта)

> > Но не просто ещё отображался топ по количеству кликов но и что бы был реализован счетчик изменений кликов за сутки

Делаешь также таблицу в которой три поля 1)Id 2)Дата 3)Кол-во кликов

> > то есть условно говоря сегодня на пять человек больше подписалось выводится +5 если отписалось то -5.

выводишь на странице значение с базы или для текущей даты если нада, или для (текущая дата минус вчерашняя дата)

Comment: "Довольно абстрактно поставлен вопрос, кнопка избранное на сайте одна или она (для данной категории,для продукта, или просто для сайта)?" это реально имеет какое то значение что работает на одной работает будет работать и на двух. 
"Делаешь также таблицу в которой три поля 1)Id 2)Дата 3)Кол-во кликов" А как дату записывать как unix или php date или просто текст? И какая должна быть таблица DATA, VARCHAR или INT